# How to create empty folder/object in Minio using python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-s3, minio

I tried below code which creates an object inside a bucket with file inside it.

```
result = client.put_object(
"my-bucket", "my-object", io.BytesIO(b"hello"), 5,
)
```

Is there a way to create empty directory/folder inside a bucket or object?

Answer (score 0):

The folder is created, when you move the object to minio, example:

```
minio = Minio(host,
              access_key=config.get('MINIO_ACCESS_KEY'),
              secret_key=config.get('MINIO_SECRET_KEY'),
              secure=False)    
minio.make_bucket(bucket_name, location="us-east-1")
minio.fput_object(bucket_name, f"{folder1}/{folder2}/filename", disk_full_filename)
```

Comment: The question is specific to the EMPTY folder.

Answer (score 0):

result = client.put_object(
"my-bucket", "my-object", io.BytesIO(b""), 0,
)

Comment: It's usually a good idea to put a few lines of text in an answer explaining why this solution works and what problem it addresses.

Comment: What is meant by this answer, is to create a path, and upload to it an empty object but 0 length. This will keep the path created